# Twitter Typeahead: Upgrading to the latest version using the same function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-typeahead

I'm currently using the Bootstrap-typeahead plugin, this way:

```
$('.patients_typeahead').typeahead({
                    name: 'patientshomepage',
                    source: function (query, process) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'source.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            query: 'query=' + query,
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            async: true,
                            success: function (data) {
                               process(data);
                            }

                        })
                    }



                });
```

I want to upgrade to the latest typeahead, but I understood that the `source: function()` isn't supported anymore. How can I convert my code so I could use the latest twitter-typeahead?

Comment: When you say "latest typeahead" what in specific are you referring to?

Comment: And what version are you using currently?

Comment: The numbers don't matter. I'm using the bootstrap-typeahead version. And the latest version of Bootstrap(3.0.2) doesn't include typeahead within it, so now it's "twitter-typeahead". how do I check the version number of the script I'm using right now? I want to upgrade to 0.9.3 I think(that's what it says on the gitHub page)

Comment: Those two libraries aren't really compatible so there is no upgrade per se.  You'll have to adapt your code to work with the twitter typeahead library.  I've found the examples to be pretty helpful when figuring out what to do.

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can learn from the examples.